# How to check laws of other kingdoms?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

How to check laws of other kingdoms?

In particular, I'm inheritance what are inheritance laws?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to check sucession laws for a title is to find the owner of that title and mouse over it on their character sheet. This will show you the law for that title, the heir, and the line of succession, i.e. who you need to get rid of to inherit it.
[image: Viewing sucession laws]

For other laws, select the De Jure Kingdoms view and mouse over the area. This will tell you laws such as regulated inheritance, or how bishops are selected. Note that these laws are based the De Jure Kingdom that county/duchy is in, if it exists, not necessarily the kingdom of its owner.
[image: Kingdom laws of Aragon. Useful for checking things suh as regulated inheritance.]